# How can I limit maximum fps with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, frame-rate

Is there any way that I can limit fps with certain value?

For example, using filter graph such as `fps=min(original_fps, MAX_FPS)`.

Comment: When do you need to do this?

Comment: @Gyan When input files are weird (eg, mp3 with album art) and ffmpeg decides the output framerate should be 90,000 Hz.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I was asking the OP, in order to decide which method would work for them.

Comment: @Gyan SO questions and answers are for everyone. That is why the same question asked by me would be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, typically the answer with ffmpeg is "not as easily as you'd like"

You can parse out the original fps, then do the "min" calculation in some pre-existing script I suppose, or you may be able to set your output to "vfr" (variable frame rate) mode, then use the select filter to try to not allow frames in too quickly. GL!

Comment: With `-vsync vfr`, just adding `-r MAX` is enough. This can mess up the encoder time base though, important in duration sensitive encoders like x264...etc